# Split Numerator and Denominator from a formula with multiple division

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse

There is logic which split and store Numerator and Denominator from the formula as present below in a 2 columns(Numerator & Denominator) in the table.

Formula:
Example1: (A/B)
Example2: (100*(A/B)) and so in.
So in the first example if I split with the below logic and then there is no issue

Numerator: `LEFT('(100*(A/B))', CHARINDEX('/', '(100*(A/B))') - 1)`
Denominator: `SUBSTRING('(100*(A/B))', CHARINDEX('/', '(100*(A/B))') + 1, LEN('(100*(A/B))'))`

But the main problem is coming when there are more than one division. Like as below.

Example3: `(100*(A/B)/C)`
So in the above case the current logic with two column doesn't feet properly.

Can someone please let me how I can break this formula and store the value in Numerator and Denominator column?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: You forgot to add what you want to retrieve for A / B / C

Comment: @siggemannen i want to retrieve Numerator and Denominator from A/B/C. So i can achieve it in that case?

Comment: Well, B is both, so my question stands

Comment: I would argue that there is indeed a major issue with even the first example. It will return "(100*(A" for the numerator and "B))" for the denominator which is just completely incorrect in both cases. I think you need to explain more clearly what you want as output here.

Comment: This might be solvable as a string parsing exercise but you'll really need to provide the most general description of the problem to get any help on it.

Comment: wasn't this btw asked recently, i remember the synapse thing because it didn't support recursive CTE which would allowed to write a simple parser

Comment: Any one  has any solution? kindly le tme know

Comment: @John I am able to achive let me know if it is ok
Formula Numerator Denominator
(A/B) (A B)
(100*(A/B)) (100*(A B))
(100*(A/B)/C) (100*(A B)/C)

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula .Can you paste the code here?

Comment: UPDATE FormulaSplitv2
SET Numerator = LEFT(Formula, CHARINDEX('/', Formula) - 1),
    Denominator = SUBSTRING(Formula, CHARINDEX('/', Formula) + 1, LEN(Formula))
WHERE CHARINDEX('/', Formula) > 0;

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula Thank yo for the reply. I was not well. SO couldn't update. So basically based one first ' /' y ou splitting the frmula and setting frist charctore(before the first '/') as numerator and rest of the part as dinominator. Then its an issue when denominator has multiple devision.

Comment: @shawnt00 can you please provide an example of string parsing in sql server. In this case we would also need to consider the BODMAS rule for correct calculation.